# PHP - Count how many times find a word from array list

Tags: php, string, search, count

first i'm sorry for bad title, my english is not good enough and my little problem is not plain (for me).

Anyway, i have a rudimental script that counts how many times appears a list of words in a string.

```
$orto1 = substr_count($text," fingger ");
$orto2 = substr_count($text," apears ");
$orto3 = substr_count($text,"ghiven");

$ortog = $orto1 + $orto2 + $orto3;
```

Now, it's very uncomfortable whenever i've to add a new word, so, i'd like put all words in a array.

So, i've tried with substr_count as well as several examples found here, unsuccessfully.

I'd like to manage to create something like that:

```
$array = array(" fingger ", " apears ", "ghiven", "suporting");
$total = substr_count($array, $mytext);
echo $total;
```

Important is case insensitive and "wildcard" matching.

Is it possible or there is another best way?

Thank you at all!
Riccardo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess a simple loop will do?

```
$total = 0
$array = array(" fingger ", " apears ", "ghiven", "suporting");
foreach($array as $word){
  $total += substr_count($word, $mytext);
}
echo $total;
```

Regarding the case-insensitivity you might use

```
substr_count(strtoupper($word), strtoupper($mytext))
```

Answer (score 0):

OMG! 
I had not thought at the simple way like a loop :-)

Anyway, there is a little error:

```
  $total += substr_count($word, $mytext);
```

The correct way is:

```
   $total += substr_count($mytext, $word);
```

Thank you so much!!!